# Remove first character in char*

Tags: c

I have a char* which has this data "asd:asdsa"

I want to remove the contents before the ':' char. How can this be done? I have seen suggestions that are ugly that need me to move the pointer but I dont want to do that?

Can I know some suggestions?

Comment: "but [you] dont want to do that?" How do we know you will want to do whatever alternative solution we propose? Please tell us what is wrong with this solution so we may avoid wasting time writing answers that suffer from the same defects.

Comment: Sometimes I'm reading the STL documentation and the function has a long name and I'm all like 'I DONT WANT TO TYPE THAT MUCH'. The stand off goes on for ages but usually the computer wins.

Answer (score 8):

In C, you could do this:

```
char *newString = originalString + 4;
```

Now if you don't want to do that, tell us why. Tell us the problem!

Also if you don't know if it is `4` or something else (which can be known at runtime only), then use a loop to find out the index of `':'` and use it in place of `4`. That is an easy task. TRY yourself. Good Luck. :-)

---

<sup>I kept this part just for learning purpose because the question was initially tagged as C++ when I wrote it, and I think it helps those C programmers who occasionally work in C++.</sup>

In C++, `std::string` simplifies lots of things you do with strings.

```
std::string s = "asd:asdsa";  //#include <string>
s = s.substr(s.find(':') + 1);
```

In this code, `substr()` returns the string after `:`, which means its value is `"asdsa"`.

See [Online Demo.](http://ideone.com/frwnZZ)

Comment: `std::string` doesn't exist in C.

Comment: @Fanael It was earlier tagges as `C++`. Now it is changed to `C`.

Comment: @Mahesh: but it's not anymore!

Comment: @Fanael: I answered it in C++, because it was tagged C++.

Comment: Who downvoted me without specifying the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say a mixture of `strchr` and `memmove` should do it.

```
char *res = strchr(str, ':');
if (res)
  memmove(str, res + 1, strlen(res + 1) + 1);
```

Comment: There's no function `strcpy(res)`...

Comment: thanks..must i delete/free res?

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior.

Comment: `strcpy()` has undefined behaviour if you copy between overlapping strings, as you will here if the `:` is in the first half of the string.  You can use `memmove(str, res + 1, strlen(res + 1) + 1)` instead.

Comment: @caf i didn't know that. `memmove` seems way better in that case, thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove it without "ugly" solution.

But you can directly use the address of the third case of the your string.

```
printf("%s\n", &str[3]);
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `strtok()`

```
char mystr[] = "asd:asdasd";
char *split;
int second = 0;

split = strtok(mystr, ":");

  while (second < 2 && split != NULL)
  {
    split = strtok (NULL, ":");
    second++;
  }
puts(split);
```

Comment: The question is c++ tagged

Comment: @nouney lol, not anymore

Comment: But he's using char* so why don't use c features

Answer (score 1):

You should use `std::string` as Nawaz says previously, but using raw pointers you can simply use `my_data`:

```
char* original_data = "asd:asdasd";
char* my_data = original_data + 4; // points to: "asdasd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C functions:

```
#include <string.h>

char *p = strchr(s, '.');

if (p != NULL)
{
    memmove(s, p + 1, strlen(p));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using char* you will have to play with the pointer
but if you are in c++ why you don't use `std::string` ?

Anyway you can use strstr for char* but you will manipulate pointer

Answer (score 0):

If the data is pointing to read only location, then you can not modify it. It can be easily done using `std::string`.

```
std::string str("asd:asdsa");
size_t loc = str.find(':') + 1;
str.erase (str.begin(), str.begin() + loc);
```

Comment: The question is tagged as C (or at least is now!)